# Change the border after I lock the form in html css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a form in Html, CSS, and jQuery. 
here When I click on the Lock button I am able to disable all the field behavior, but unfortunately, I could not hide the border. Means, if a value is there it should not show the border, but on hover, it should show the hover behavior. If no value is in the field it should show border-bottom only and hover behavior as usual. Can you please check my fiddle, that will help in better understanding.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  alert("The Button was clicked.");
  $('#selectBox').css('pointer-events', 'none');
  $(".userInput").prop("disabled", true);

});
```

```css
p {
  color: #505050 !important;
  margin-top: 7px;
  font-size: 15px !important;
  font-family: Segoe\000020UI, Tahoma, Arial;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
}

.heading {
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
  border-top: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-left: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-right: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  height: 40px;
}

.contentBody {
  font-family: Segoe\000020UI, Tahoma, Arial;
  width: 100%;
}

.tab-container {
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.tab-navigation {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.tab-content {
  font-family: Segoe\000020UI, Tahoma, Arial;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 96.5%;
  height: auto;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.contentLabel {
  color: #505050 !important;
  font-family: Segoe\000020UI, Tahoma, Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

#selectBox {
  width: 300px;
  color: #505050 !important;
  font-family: Segoe\000020UI, Tahoma, Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 7.4%;
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

.label {
  color: #505050 !important;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 280px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Segoe\000020UI, Tahoma, Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.userInput {
  color: #505050 !important;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
  border: 0px;
  border-bottom: 0.7px dashed #505050;
  font-family: Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 1px;
  outline: 0;
  text-indent: 2px;
}

.userInput:hover,
.userInput:focus {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: text;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px !important;
  padding-left: 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #666;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #666;
  text-align: left;
}

.userInput:focus:valid {
  border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

.userInput:valid {
  border: 0px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

.spaning {
  margin-left: -317px;
}

.spaning:before {
  content: '$';
  color: red;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.5s;
  -o-transition: color 0.5s;
  transition: color 0.5s;
}

.dollarReq {
  border-bottom: 0.7px dashed #505050;
  /*looks before entering anything in field*/
}

.dollarReq:focus {
  border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

.dollarReq:focus+.spaning:before {
  content: '$';
  color: orange;
}

.dollarReq:focus:valid {
  border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

.dollarReq:focus:valid+.spaning:before {
  content: '$';
  color: yellow;
}

.dollarReq:valid {
  border: 0px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

.dollarReq:valid+.spaning:before {
  content: '$';
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contentBody" id="content_wrapper">

  <div class="heading">
    <p>Heading</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-container">


    <div class="tab-navigation">
      <span class="contentLabel" id="contentType">Property Finance type : </span>
      <select id="selectBox">
        <option value="10">Value1</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="tab-10" class="tab tab-content">
      <div>
        <label class="label">Value2</label>
        <input class="userInput dollarReq" type="text" autocomplete="off" required />
        <span class="spaning" for="input"></span>



      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="label">Value3</label>
        <input class="userInput dollarReq" type="text" autocomplete="off" required />
        <span class="spaning" for="input"></span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="label">Value4</label>
        <input class="userInput" type="text" autocomplete="off" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="label">Value5</label>
        <input class="userInput" type="text" autocomplete="off" required />
      </div>


    </div>
    <button type="submit">
            Lock
            </button>



  </div>
</div>
<!--property finance Body-->
```

Comment: "If no value is in the field" Which field do you mean? There are several.

Comment: if any one field is empty it should show border-bottom, if field is valid it should not show border

Comment: That's working already with your code...

Comment: No,it is not, when there is a value in the field, it should not show border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should write some jQuery for class adding after field value is inserted.

jQuery code will be something like that:

```
$("input").on('change', function() {
 if($(this).value) {
   $(this).addClass('userInput-valid');
 }

});
```

CSS like this:

```
.userInput-valid {
    border: 0px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
}
```

Try to fix this with some jQuery. CSS, not every time will help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

addClass "form-locked" on your form if locked. You'll need to use js to listen to keyup on the input fields then addClass "notEmpty", then css .form-locked .dollarReq.notEmpty {border-bottom:0;}

Comment: can you pls help me with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/indhu_velayutham/5euc6sqy/